# Is it mandatory to reindex all indexes everyday?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is it mandatory to reindex all indexes everyday? What are the mandatory ones and what are the optional ones? Below is the crontab details I have and I see some indexers run and some don't. The ones with Jan 7 date were run manually by reindex command yesterday.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/site/web/site.com/public_html/bin/magento cron:run &> /dev/null
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/site/web/site.com/public_html/update/cron.php &> /dev/null
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/site/web/site.com/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run &> /dev/null
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to run indexing everyday, you only have to run when any index will be invalidated. As per screenshot it seems your indexing will run when you update and save any module like when you save any product, product related indexing will run i.e product flat data and so on.

**Reindexing can be performed in two modes:**

**Update on Save** - index tables are updated immediately after the dictionary data is changed.
**Update by Schedule** - index tables are updated by cron job according to the configured schedule.

To set these options:

1. Log in to the Magento Admin .
2. Click System > Index Management.
3. Select the checkbox next to each type of indexer to change.
4. From the Actions list, click the indexing mode.
5. Click Submit.

**You can reindex by:**

**Using a cron job**, which is **preferred** because indexing runs every minute.

Using the magento indexer:reindex [indexer] command, which reindexes selected indexers, or all indexers, one time only.

So I think you have to change indexer mode to **Using a cron job** so you don't have to bother about indexing manually daily.

Comment: I already have a cron job as you can see from above.

Comment: But your indexer seems to be set as Update on Save instead of Update by Schedule, so CRON will not help in your current mode

Comment: Thank you. is it  okay to truncate cron_schedule table?

Comment: Yes you can, just take a back of this table before truncate, so that if any thing goes wrong you can restore it